# Show only certain processes?

Tags: c#, process

```
private void UpdateProcessList()
    {
        // clear the existing list of any items
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        // loop through the running processes and add
        //each to the list
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName + " - " + p.Id);
        }
        // display the number of running processes in
        // a status message at the bottom of the page
        listBox1.Text = "Processes running: " +
        listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pi.Verb = "runas";
        pi.FileName = "1-AccountServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "2-DatabaseServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "3-CoreServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "4-CacheServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "5-Certifier.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "6-LoginServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pi.FileName = "7-WorldServer.exe";
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(pi);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }
```

The question is I don't want every process to show but just these seven particular processes, how do I do it? It does work but not the way I actually want it to >.< I have been searching for a while on the internet to actually find this code and implemented it to what I wanted but it just shows so many processes which for what I want it for is pointless.

Comment: Limit the processes you need by first adding them to a collection, such as a list, and then using a linq query to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a List(of String) with all of your processes names

```
List<string> myProcesses = new List<string>() 
{
    "1-AccountServer.exe","2-DatabaseServer.exe",
    "3-CoreServer.exe", "4-CacheServer.exe","5-Certifier.exe",
    "6-LoginServer.exe","7-WorldServer.exe"
};
```

and then check

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{ 
     if(myProcesses.Contains(p.ProcessName + ".exe"))
        listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName + " - " + p.Id);
}
```

by the way, creating this list could help a lot also to build a common method that launches all the processes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    pi.Verb = "runas";
    pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    foreach(string s in myProcesses)
    {
         pi.FileName = s;
         Process.Start(pi);
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
 }
```

**EDIT** as suggested by IV4 in its comment, perhaps a different approach that gathers all the processes in a HashSet and then check the List (only 7 elements) against the HashSet could be better in terms of performance

```
HashSet<Process> anHashOfProcesses = new HashSet<Process>(Process.GetProcesses());
foreach(string s in myProcesses)
{
    var p = anHashOfProcesses.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ProcessName + ".exe" == s);
    if(p != null) listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName + " - " + p.Id);
}
```

Comment: I would use `HashSet` instead of list.

Comment: GAH I can't get it to work but I'm thinking it's because it checks processes before they start and not after they have started? The processes actually start but they still don't show in the listbox?

I need to show all of my code >.< But I don't know how to :(

Comment: Probably it is because the ProcessName doesn't contain the extensions. Fixing the answer

Comment: However the comment from @I4V made me think of a different approach.

Comment: aHash does not exist in the current context >.<

Comment: Yup I reloaded the page and noticed it was changed from aHash lol. However I still don't see the processes running in the list box albeit they are opened.

Comment: using the first loop try to add a Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName) before the if test and check what is the processnames returned. Contains and "==" are case sensitive

Comment: Can't I just check Task Manager to see what the process name is?

Comment: Okay I got it to work kind of, just shows me more than process running but I'll keep looking into it, again thank you guys :)